# Black screen on Intel graphics after screen replacement

Tags: windows-7, drivers, display, graphics-card, intel-graphics

Recently my laptop screen had to be replaced due to a cracked screen. Original screen was a Samsung and the new screen is LG. After this, whenever I install Intel HD graphics, windows boots up till the login screen and then goes black, one bright flicker, then completely black again. However, when I boot into safe mode and replace Intel HD graphics driver with Standard VGA adapter, everything works fine, except for crappy graphics of course. I tried installing various old/new/latest versions of driver software, upgrade/downgrade BIOS, install monitor.inf file from lenovo website for this laptop model, everything.

Odd thing: running Dxdiag shows my current display to be 1200x800 (32bit)(1hz).
So, I tried to change the display refresh rate in advanced settings> Screen refresh rate, no luck, no other option except ' Use hardware defaults'. So, I went ahead an modified registry values as given here:
[How to Modify the Video Refresh Frequency in the Registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216166/en-us).

Again, no use. After I reboot and go back and check, its set to 1 by default.

Tried 4 clean installs, installing on a completely new HDD, Windows 7 Pro, Windows 7 Ultimate, Windows 8 , everything..
Ubuntu works fine, no problems.

Is it a screen problem? Or some hardware ID kind of thing? 
What should I do ?
Please help!

**Dxdiag information:**

```
------------------
System Information
------------------
Time of this report: 2/3/2015, 06:26:14
       Machine name: UNKNOWN-PC
   Operating System: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1 (7601.win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)
           Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
System Manufacturer: LENOVO
       System Model: 3626AG2
               BIOS: Ver 1.00PARTTBLx
          Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 520  @ 2.40GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.4GHz
             Memory: 4096MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 3892MB RAM
          Page File: 2051MB used, 5730MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\Windows
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
   User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
 System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
    DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
     DxDiag Version: 6.01.7601.17514 32bit Unicode

------------
DxDiag Notes
------------
      Display Tab 1: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 1: No problems found.
          Input Tab: No problems found.

--------------------
DirectX Debug Levels
--------------------
Direct3D:    0/4 (retail)
DirectDraw:  0/4 (retail)
DirectInput: 0/5 (retail)
DirectMusic: 0/5 (retail)
DirectPlay:  0/9 (retail)
DirectSound: 0/5 (retail)
DirectShow:  0/6 (retail)

---------------
Display Devices
---------------
          Card name: Standard VGA Graphics Adapter
       Manufacturer: (Standard display types)
          Chip type: Intel(R) HD Graphics (Core i5)
           DAC type: Internal
         Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0046&SUBSYS_215A17AA&REV_02
     Display Memory: 1721 MB
   Dedicated Memory: n/a
      Shared Memory: n/a
       Current Mode: 1280 x 800 (32 bit) (1Hz)
       Monitor Name: ThinkPad Display 1280x800
      Monitor Model: 
         Monitor Id: 
        Native Mode: 
        Output Type: 
        Driver Name: igdumd64.dll,igd10umd64.dll,igdumdx32,igd10umd32
Driver File Version: 8.15.0010.2993 (English)
     Driver Version: 6.1.7600.16385
        DDI Version: unknown
       Driver Model: unknown
  Driver Attributes: Final Retail
   Driver Date/Size: 2/20/2013 03:14:11, 8314368 bytes
        WHQL Logo'd: n/a
    WHQL Date Stamp: n/a
  Device Identifier: {D7B78E66-4306-11CF-1B34-EA1CACC2CB35}
          Vendor ID: 0x8086
          Device ID: 0x0046
          SubSys ID: 0x215A17AA
        Revision ID: 0x0002
 Driver Strong Name: Unknown
     Rank Of Driver: Unknown
        Video Accel: 
      Deinterlace Caps: n/a
       D3D9 Overlay: n/a
            DXVA-HD: n/a
       DDraw Status: Not Available
         D3D Status: Not Available
         AGP Status: Not Available
```

Comment: What is the actual make and model of this laptop? Have you taken it back to the service technician who replaced the display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technician who replaced your screen has almost certainly supplied an incompatible LCD panel.

Installing the Intel Graphics driver activates all the advanced graphics features including LCD screen power/brightness/sleep control plus any other special OEM enhancements Lenovo has implemented themselves. This all requires a compatible LCD panel. It's not like desktop PCs where you can use any monitor you like.

I'm afraid the only real fix is to go back to your technician and ask them to source a genuine compatible replacement LCD for your laptop. Unfortunately the cost of genuine/properly compatible parts is usually high.

Comment: Yes, I did check the user manual and the new screen is not in the list of compatible monitors.
I'll take it back to the technician and get it replaced.
Thank you for pointing it out.